# Htaccess and time variables - Server time or UTC?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Forgive me if this is a trivial question, but does anyone know (with documentation) if the htaccess date and time [server variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (e.g. TIME_MIN, TIME_HOUR, etc.) represent the server time or UTC?

According to the latest [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars):

> TIME_HOUR The hour part of the current time (0, ..., 23)

What is this "current time"? Server time or UTC? I tried searching the docs with <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and "UTC", "GMT", "server time" but no matches. Google isn't helpful either. I suspect it's the server time, but I want to be sure when writing rules like this (e.g. block access from 1 am to 8 am):

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR} ^(01|02|03|04|05|06|07)
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#vars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mod_rewrite.c](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/f6b43bb91925d2950965d3ac8572d58a277d2351/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c):

```
if (!strcmp(var, "TIME_HOUR")) {
    apr_time_exp_lt(&tm, apr_time_now());
    return apr_psprintf(r->pool, "%02d", tm.tm_hour);
}
```

[apr_time_exp_lt](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__time.html#ga34d3b9858de1d3111a4b2ff936ada7f6): Convert a time to its human readable components **in the local timezone**.

A little experiment verified it also.

Comment: Clever idea looking into the source. I was hoping for official documentation, but this is the next best thing. As a side note, the "%02d" part differs from the official docs which says the output will be (0, ..., 23). This means, and it makes sense, that the first 9 hours will be padded with a zero. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, given the error in the docs, it is not "the next best thing", it is **the** best thing :)